# Django Python and Arduino

Tags: python, django, database, arduino

I wonder if anyone has an example of how to connect an arduino to django to resivir and send data at the same arduino , and I want to keep shares in the database django of actions that make arduino and send actions django to arduino for which also make actions, where in the project django I make the connection.

I hope your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

you can visite this link below :
https://alejandrok5.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/arduino-with-django-and-python/
use the library  serial (pip install PySerial)
this is for connection with arduino

```
ser = serial.Serial("PORT", NUMSERIAL, timeout=1)  
sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser))
```

- to send data : `ser.write(bytearray(code, "utf-8"))`
- to read use this : `donnee = str(ser.readline()[:-2])`